# Access nested values in FormattedMessage

Tags: react-intl

Trying to get the following to work, but it seems that `react-intl` doesn't support it. Curious to know if there are any alternatives? Seems like it might be a common probably

```
<FormattedMessage 
  values={{session:{user:{first_name:'fred'}}}} 
  defaultMessage="Hello {session.user.first_name}!"
/>
```

Outputs:

```
Hello {session.user.first_name}!
```

Desired:

```
Hello fred!
```

Answer (score 0):

`.` is not a valid ICU argument token, which is why `react-intl` doesn't support it.